# Working with files Android programming

Tags: java, android

I need your help.
So, what i intend to do is to read a value from a file and to increase this value by one, then write it in the same file, i don`t know where is my error.
This is the procedure which i use to do all of this : [image: Procedure code]

And together with the folders :[image: folders]

I really appreciate your help until now, would be really thankful for any advice.
The problem i am facing i can`t find the file on device, the text file should be a permanent file created on the device in order to store some data, even if the app is closed or the phone is switched off.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? Do you have file system permissions in your manifest?

Comment: What's the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: If you just want to store some Integer then saving it in a [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) should be the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you in android you can't access file like you did with direct path

```
 new File("./data/text2.txt");
```

You can use the Eniornment class to get  the path to data folder than here create the your file and save the values.
For example :

```
 String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
 if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
     File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
     File file = new File(path, "text2.txt");
     // from here you read and write like you already did.
 }
```

However if you only need to write an Integer you can use SheredPreferences like this:

```
 //get the value
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
 int test = settings.getInt("test", -1); 
 test++;
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putInt("test", test);
 editor.apply();
```